# express middle ware not logging to the console

Tags: javascript, express

Im setting up an express server and I want to console.log() something every time you load a page successfully.

```
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res, next){                       
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");                               
    next();                                                                
});                                                                    

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){                             
    console.log("test");                                                   
});
```

I expected it to `console.log("test")` every time you go to the page called index.html, but instead it doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 3):

`app.get` registers a **route**, not middleware.

Since you have registered 2 routes for `/index.html`, the first one is found and the second one is never reached.

You need `app.use` to register middleware.

---

Also, the middleware needs to call the third argument of the callback to indicate when it is finished.

---

Order matters. You need to register you middleware before the route, otherwise, the route will get the request, respond to it, then stop.

---

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Middleware");
    next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, world");
});

app.listen(8080);
```

---

Further reading: [Using middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: I tried what you said and It still didnt console.log("test").

Comment: @fro9epicness — It works fine here — https://i.imgur.com/Rax1qjj.png — you must have missed a step.